# Identify these (Technic Steering) parts?

Tags: piece-information, technic, part-identification

These three parts do not have part numbers on them, but it is clear they are LEGO parts (they have LEGO printed on them).  I am trying to track down the set that these belong to, or at least a part number.  Any help would be appreciated.
[image: top view of unknown parts]
[image: angle view, disassembled]

Answer (score 9):

These parts were used for steering in many Technic sets between 1988 and 2001. They are the following parts:

- [Technic Steering Gear Holder (2790)](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/2790)
- [Technic Steering Rack (2791)](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/2791)
- [Technic Steering Top (2792)](http://peeron.com/inv/parts/2792)

Here's an example of how they can be used together for steering from set 8022:

[image: 8022 Steering]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a listing from bricklink for the rack for which sets it was in.

http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=2791&in=S

Part numbers can be used for the other items.